# Getting some errors after refreshing the react page

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I'm creating a basic auth using Google in **React page**.

**[image: 1]**

After refreshing page getting error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accounts')**

**[image: 2]**

but starting of the page and after **several times refreshing the page and clear console the error is gone**

**[image: 3]**

and again error comes back.

Is this is a correct script to use google auth ?? Because after using this i got an error but **google is not define** but then i had to define google in App.js page.

Kindly let me know where the actual error. I think error is under **script** in index.html.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

const google = window.google;


function App() {

  const [ user, setUser ] = useState({});

  function handleCallbackResponse(response) {
    console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
    var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    console.log(userObject);
    
    setUser(userObject);
    document.getElementById("signInDiv").hidden = true;
  }


  function handleSignOut(event) {
    setUser({});
    document.getElementById("signInDiv").hidden = false;
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    // google from script in index.html

    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "xxx",
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    });

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("signInDiv"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }
    );

    google.accounts.id.prompt();

  }, []);
  
  // If there is signed in user then show sign out button
  // If there is no user then show sign in button

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="signInDiv"></div>
        { 
          Object.keys(user).length != 0 &&
          <button onClick={(e) => handleSignOut(e)}>Sign Out</button>
        }

        { user &&
          <div>
            <img src={user.picture} alt="" />
            <h3>{user.name}</h3>
          </div>
        }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `async defer` on your `<script />` tag that is loading the SDK. This basically means that the code isn't critical and the browser can load your code as late as it wants. When you reload the page there is a chance that the `SDK` gets ran before that `useEffect` runs in which case it will work. If the `useEffect` runs first, then `google` would be `undefined`. You should review the SDK documentation and see if they have some mechanism of telling you when it is fully loaded and ready (like maybe they dispatch an event or something). Otherwise you could remove the `async defer` from the `script` although I wouldn't recommend this

Comment: yeah... thank you very much. The error is gone for now by removing `async defer` and i'll definitely see the sdk docs. And now can you tell me why i'm redirecting to different web tab after clicking the google account and getting this error... **Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.postMessage call.**  Instead of redirecting to different website i need a pop up on same my react page. How can i do that ??

Comment: No problem! I would try to solve that on your own for a while and if you need help then ask another question. Good luck!